# Group by query in Django ORM

Tags: python, django, orm

I an having a confusion on how to write a django query to get my data. I have 2 tables '**ticket**' and '**ticket_details**'. Below is the schema for them.

```
Ticket(id, name, type, user)
TicketDetails(ticket_id, message, created_time)
```

*Note: Multiple message can be associated to one ticket id.*

And **ticket_id** is a **foreign key** to the **Ticket** table.

I would like to fetch all the columns from both the table where only the latest message from the TicketDetails table should be picked for a particular ticket id.

```
Example:
Ticket
id, name, type, user
1,install, application, usr1

TicketDetails
ticket_id, message, creted_time
1, <message1>, 12:00 PM
1, <message2>, 04:00 PM
2, <message3>, 05:00 PM -->latest entry

Expected Output:
id, name, type, user, message, created_time
1, install, application, usr1, <message3>, 05:00PM
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you give an formal example ?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to fetch data from both tables based on `ticket_id`?

Comment: `Ticket.objects.filter(id=1234).select_related('TicketDetails').latest('created_time')` ??? let me know if it works or not

Comment: @k33da_the_bug no it does not work. I have added an example if that helps you understand what i am asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some assumptions about your models, you didn't provide any:

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)


# Model names should NEVER end with "s"
class TicketDetail(models.Model):
    ticket = models.ForeignKey(Ticket, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    created_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

You have 2 options:

1. you can write it in pure sql, you lose the ability to filter

   ```
   sql = """
   SELECT ticket.id, ticket.name, ticket.type, ticket.user_id, detail.message
     FROM {ticket} ticket
     LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT detail.ticket_id, detail.message 
         FROM {detail} detail
        INNER JOIN (
           SELECT MAX(id) id, ticket_id 
             FROM {detail} 
            GROUP BY ticket_id
       ) detail_message ON detail.id = detail_message.id
   ) detail ON detail.ticket_id = ticket.id
   """.format(ticket=Ticket._meta.db_table, detail=TicketDetail._meta.db_table)
   tickets = Ticket.objects.raw(sql)

   for ticket in tickets:
       print(ticket.id, ticket.message)
   ```
2. Write it in the "django" way

   ```
   latest_messages = TicketDetail.objects.values('ticket_id').annotate(id=models.Max('id')).values('id')
   tickets = Ticket.objects.prefetch_related(models.Prefetch('ticketdetail_set', TicketDetail.objects.filter(id__in=latest_messages))).order_by('id')

   for ticket in tickets:
       print(ticket.id)
       # this iteration will only ever yield 1 result.. or nothing.
       for detail in ticket.ticketdetail_set.all():
           print(detail.message)
   ```

---

Here are the tests:

```
 # uses factoryboy and faker to fill in the data

 class UserFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = auth.models.User
        django_get_or_create = ('username',)

    first_name = fake.first_name()
    last_name = fake.last_name()
    email = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda obj: "{}.{}@gmail.com".format(obj.last_name, obj.first_name).lower())
    username = factory.Sequence(lambda n: 'user' + str(n))


class SimpleTestCase(TestCase):
    
    def setUp(self):
        ticket1 = Ticket.objects.create(user=UserFactory(), type='A', name='Number 1')
        TicketDetail.objects.create(ticket=ticket1, message='you wont see this')
        TicketDetail.objects.create(ticket=ticket1, message='you wont see this either')
        TicketDetail.objects.create(ticket=ticket1, message='YES!!')

        ticket2 = Ticket.objects.create(user=UserFactory(), type='B', name='Number 2')
        TicketDetail.objects.create(ticket=ticket2, message='you also wont see this')
        TicketDetail.objects.create(ticket=ticket2, message='you also wont see this either')
        TicketDetail.objects.create(ticket=ticket2, message='also YES!!')

    def test_flatten_pure_sql(self):
        sql = """
        SELECT ticket.id, ticket.name, ticket.type, ticket.user_id, detail.message
          FROM {ticket} ticket
          LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT detail.ticket_id, detail.message 
              FROM {detail} detail
             INNER JOIN (
                SELECT MAX(id) id, ticket_id 
                  FROM {detail} 
                 GROUP BY ticket_id
            ) detail_message ON detail.id = detail_message.id
        ) detail ON detail.ticket_id = ticket.id
        """.format(ticket=Ticket._meta.db_table, detail=TicketDetail._meta.db_table)
        self.assertEquals(['YES!!', 'also YES!!'], [x.message for x in Ticket.objects.raw(sql)])

    def test_orm_way(self):
        latest_messages = TicketDetail.objects.values('ticket_id').annotate(id=models.Max('id')).values('id')
        tickets = Ticket.objects.prefetch_related(models.Prefetch('ticketdetail_set', TicketDetail.objects.filter(id__in=latest_messages))).order_by('id')
        self.assertEquals(['Number 1', 'Number 2'], [x.name for x in tickets])
        self.assertEquals(['YES!!'], [x.message for x in tickets[0].ticketdetail_set.all()])
        self.assertEquals(['also YES!!'], [x.message for x in tickets[1].ticketdetail_set.all()])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I get it now.